# Change of measure in an integral

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

As I continue going through random processes with Krylov, I came across a proof where he replaces the measure $\Lambda$ with a new measure $\mu$, defined by
$$ \mu(\Gamma)=\int_\Gamma \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda(dx)+I_{\Gamma}(0)\sigma^2,$$
where $I_\Gamma(x)$ is the indicator function.

Here, I can't figure out how to write $\mu(dx)$ in terms of $\Lambda(dx)$ (we need to replace $\Lambda(dx)$ by $\mu(dx)$ in an integral). Can someone offer me guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any non-negative measurable function $f$ we have $\int fd\mu=\int f(x)\frac {x^{2}}{1+x^{2}} \Lambda (dx)+f(0)\sigma ^{2}$.

For a proof verify this for simple functions and take limits. The equation extends to measurable functions which are not non-negative provided either of the two integrals on the left  exists.